# JqueryMobile enable disabled elements doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, select, properties

I disable a `<select>`-Element with following code:

```
$('#input_password').prop('disabled', 'true');
```

That works fine! But if i try to reenable this element it doesn't work:

```
$('#input_password').removeProp('disabled');
```

Yes, there are a lot of hits on google, but i tried already out many potential solutions and now i'm frustrated because i invested more than 3 hours here at work.

Thankt you very much for tips.

Comment: [.removeProp()](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) _Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead._

Comment: I used attr() and removeAttr now for disabling and enabling the element. This works. Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: `.prop()` would be the right way to go. You just have to use it the right way (as described in the documentation). disable: `.prop("disabled", true)`, enable: `.prop("disabled", false)`

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with `input`, you need to use `.textinput()` widget to disable/enable text field.

- Disable

  ```
  $(".selector").textinput("disable");
  ```
- Enable

  ```
  $(".selector").textinput("enable");
  ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Y7MtE/)**